# setvbuf not changing buffer size?

Tags: c, glibc

I have the following toy code to test out I/O buffering on `fread`, and I'm getting results that I didn't expect:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio_ext.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char buff[255];
    fp = fopen("/home/install.sh", "r");
    int result = setvbuf(fp, NULL, _IOFBF, 700); // set buffering size to some arbitrary value, say 700
    printf("Result of setting buffer: %d\n", result ); // "Result of setting buffer: 0"
    printf("Buffer size: %zd\n", __fbufsize(fp) ); // "Buffer size: 4096"


    fread(buff, 255, 1, fp);
    printf("%s\n", buff ); // prints 255 bytes as I would expect

}
```

From above, it seems like the `setvbuf` call was successful as it returned `0`, however the buffer size stays at `4096`. Moreover, I tried printing out `BUFSIZ` and it says `8192`. Running `strace` does show the underlying `read` call as being `4096` bytes. Turning off buffering seems to work fine, as buffer size gets set to 1.

Moreover, I don't understand why `BUFSIZ` (`8192`) is not the same as the default value of these reads (`4096`).

I tried many different values for the buffer size but to no avail.

I am running `ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1) 2.27`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> setvbuf not changing buffer size?

[Glibc setvbuf implementation](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/libio/iosetvbuf.c#L45) just ignores the `size` argument when `mode == _IOFBF` and `buff == NULL`. Which is fine - characteristics of buffering modes are implementation defined. And `__fbufsize` is a nonstandard extensions. Generally you shouldn't depend on the buffering of the underlying `FILE`.

> I don't understand why BUFSIZ (8192) is not the same as the default value of these reads (4096).

`Glibc` does [mmap](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/libio/fileops.c#L562) the file. Because of `mmap` the size get's [rounded](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/libio/fileops.c#L563) to [page size](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpagesize.2.html).

Comment: set `buff` to non `NULL` value works.

Answer (score 0):

I read the following here https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf:

> Not all size bytes will necessarily be used for buffering: the actual
>   buffer size is usually rounded down to a multiple of 2, a multiple of
>   page size, etc.
>
> **On many implementations, line buffering is only available for terminal
>   input streams.**

So maybe it doesn't work for a file handle on your system.

And if it does work, I can imagine values smaller than the allocation unit size on your file system don't make much sense (which may well be 8192).

Comment: I appreciate the response. However, I don't think that's the case. It works just fine when the buffer passed to `setvbuf` is non-null, however, when it is null, it doesn't seem to work at all no matter what file handle I'm using `stdin/stdout` or varying the size from values between 200 to 50000 I tried.

Comment: I are trying with strange values. Have you tried sticking to powers of 2 (e.g. 16384)?